# jquery form plugin send/get disabled select value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I use the Jquery_Form plugin and i would like to get the value of disabled select box.

HTML form :

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
 <select name="myselect" id="myselect">
  <option value="1">Option1</option>
  <option value="2">Option2</option>
  <option value="3">Option3</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Javascript :

```
<script>
$('#myselect').val('2').attr('disabled', true);

$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        target:        '#response',
    }; 

    $('#myform').ajaxForm(options); 
}); 
</script>
```

PHP :

```
if (isset($_POST['myselect']))
 echo $_POST['myselect'];
else
 echo "Oups nothing :(";
```

I always "get Oups nothing"

Answer (score 1):

The value of a disabled input/select box is not transmitted. How about disabling all non-selected values instead?

```
$('#myselect option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately I can't implement it that way, because i would like to disable the selectbox.

Answer (score 0):

is method not methode (see the form) soo is not $_POST is Anything

```
<form id="myform" methode="post"> //NO
<form id="myform" method="post"> //YES
```

Comment: yes it was a mistake, I corrected it :), but still doesn't work

Comment: yes same thing, i think that we can't send a disabled selectbox

Comment: why you use disabled, true ?

Answer (score 0):

Finaly i think that i have to put a hidden input that contain the value.

example :

```
<select name="myselect" id="myselect" disabled>
  <option value="1">Option1</option>
  <option value="2">Option2</option>
  <option value="3">Option3</option>
 </select>

<input type="hidden" name="myselect" value="2">
```

Or just remove "disabled" before sending :

```
 $('form').bind('submit', function() {
        $(this).find(':disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a value from a particular selectList's item, can you try with:

```
$('#myselect option:contains(1)').val();
```

Cheers.